# Sort unique array by id and keeping last value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have following

```
let arr = [
  { id: 1, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "a" },
  { id: 2, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "b" },
  { id: 3, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "c" },
  { id: 4, referenceId: 4, type: "normal", name: "d" },
  { id: 5, referenceId: 5, type: "chat", name: "e" },
  { id: 6, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "f" }
];
```

I want output like following :

```
[
  { id: 1, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "a" },
  { id: 2, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "b" },
  { id: 4, referenceId: 4, type: "normal", name: "d" },
  { id: 5, referenceId: 5, type: "chat", name: "e" },
  { id: 6, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "f" }
];
```

I want to sort if type === "chat", Try like this(type === "normal", no sort) :

```
arr.filter(item => {
  if (item.type === "normal") {
    return item
  }
  //sort array by referenceId and keeping last item

})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm a bit confused by your logic in the `filter` callback. What does `item.type === "normal"` have to do with the rest of your specification?

Comment: only  sort type === "chat", if type === "normal"  no sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a mapping of `referenceId -> lastIndex`, then look up the index in your `filter` to keep only indices that match the last for that `referenceId`. A check is made to ensure we're only filtering out `type: "chat"` items. Time complexity is linear.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "a" },
  { id: 2, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "b" },
  { id: 3, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "c" },
  { id: 4, referenceId: 4, type: "normal", name: "d" },
  { id: 5, referenceId: 5, type: "chat", name: "e" },
  { id: 6, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "f" }
];

const lastIdxes = arr.reduce((a, e, i) => {
  a[e.referenceId] = i;
  return a;
}, {});
const result = arr.filter((e, i) => 
  e.type !== "chat" || i === lastIdxes[e.referenceId]
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce like this,

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 1, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "a" },
  { id: 2, referenceId: 2, type: "normal", name: "b" },
  { id: 3, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "c" },
  { id: 4, referenceId: 4, type: "normal", name: "d" },
  { id: 5, referenceId: 5, type: "chat", name: "e" },
  { id: 6, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "f" }
];

res = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  index = prev.findIndex(item => item.referenceId === curr.referenceId);
  if(index > -1) {
    prev.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  prev.push(curr);
  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

sort by id as indicated in the title of this question, and then track when are the duplicates to drop

```js
// sort by id and drop referenceId duplicates
const arr = [
  { id: 1, referenceId: 1, type: "normal", name: "a" },
  { id: 2, referenceId: 2, type: "normal", name: "b" },
  { id: 3, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "c" },
  { id: 4, referenceId: 4, type: "normal", name: "d" },
  { id: 5, referenceId: 5, type: "chat", name: "e" },
  { id: 6, referenceId: 3, type: "chat", name: "f" }
];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);

const toDrop = [];
const mapper = {};
arr.forEach((curr, i) => {
    if (mapper[curr.referenceId] !== undefined) {
    toDrop.unshift(mapper[curr.referenceId]);
  }
  mapper[curr.referenceId] = i;
});

toDrop.forEach(i => {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
});

console.log(arr);
```